# How often can one visit Singapore on a Short Term Visit Pass?

Tags: visas, singapore, repeat-visits

Foreigner married to a Singapore Permanent Resident would like to come regularly to visit his/her spouse. Does anyone has experience on the number of visits on short term visit pass that the person can do?

Comment: has been rejected and 2 appeals refused already. Looking for alternatives

Comment: Dear pnuts,
this is not a helpful comment. Simply trying to figure out if someone has experience with a similar situation. Its not the question of Singapore tourist sights being numerous or not. But thank you

Comment: This is a channel hopping question with a family reunion premise. It's best handled at Expats. Voting to close as 'off-topic', sorry...